# JxBrowser requires 'package sun.awt.windows'

Tags: osgi-bundle, jxbrowser

When deploying JxBrowser with [OSGi](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000068186-osgi), I end up with the following error when I try to build my product :

```
[ant] !MESSAGE Missing requirement: JxBrowser 6.6.1 6.6.1 (com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium 6.6.1) requires 'package sun.awt.windows 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

the sun.awt.windows package is part of the JRE (in rt.jar), and I don't really understand why the JxBrowser OSGi bundles cannot find it. Any idea as to why this is would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try removing the package from the Import-Package attribute in the manifest file of jxbrowser-6.6.1.jar and see if it helps. At least in our test Eclipse OSGi example this package is required to run a simple OSGi example.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the package import from the manifest file, like [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459345/vladimir) suggested solved the problem.